# ¿Cómo ejecutar este código de CURL en PHP?

Tags: php, json, curl

¿Alguien sabe decirme como puedo hacer para ejecutar este código en PHP? Soy capaz de ejecutarlo desde la consola pero no así desde PHP.

Gracias!

```
curl -X POST https://api.printnode.com/printjobs \
        -u *********: \
        -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
        -d '{
                "printerId": 69855924,
                "title": "Comanda 1",
                "contentType": "raw_base64",
                "content": "http:\/\/sometest.com\/pdfhere",
                "source": "api documentation!"
        }'
```

Answer (score 0):

Para ejecutar un cURl yo lo hago de esta forma

Sin Autenticación

```
<?php

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.printnode.com/printjobs",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);
echo $response;
```

Con Autenticación

```
<?php

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.printnode.com/printjobs",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "Authorization: Basic NGZlNXZkZw=="
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);
echo $response;
```

Esta autenticación es tipo Basic Auth y la contraseña utiliza la función de php

```
base64_encode($password)
```

Espero te sirva de algo

Comment: Muchísimas gracias! Clarísimo, para añadir un payload JSON, cual es la mejor manera?

Answer (score -1):

hay varias maneras de ejecutar curl en php, puedes mirar la siguiente documentación oficial [curl](https://www.php.net/manual/es/curl.examples-basic.php)

Comment: Aunque teoricamente este enlace conteste la pregunta, es preferible que incluyas las partes esenciales del mismo en la respuesta. Los enlaces pueden caducar y desaparecer. Ademas llevar al usuario a que lea en otro lugar la respuesta, no es la mejor opción.